# How to combine two objects? Blending a face into an apple?

Tags: mesh, append

[image: This is what I'm trying to do]

I'm trying to add two objects together, one being a face and the other being an apple. I have it all lined up so I can put them together but I can't edit more than one object at once to do so. Is there any way I can edit these both at the same time or combine them into the same object?

Answer (score 0):

With these many vertices, aligning the verts is difficult. If you know how to scupt, try to sculpt the meshes first. Otherwise, make the vertex count the same on both meshes first, then bridge the edge loops and use the shrinkwarp modifier to create a good shape. Attach the blend file if you can, so that we can help you better.

Comment: What are you implying with the last sentence, could you please explain it further?

Comment: If you know how to sculpt , then i think its easier to sculpt these kind of meshes. Joining them is pain in the ass.(Was that the last sentense you were referring to?)

Comment: The last part of the question I figured out on my own. I was referring to how I would be able to join them into the same object so I could attach them together. How exactly would I be able to sculpt these together? I'm newer to Blender and have no idea how to sculpt.

Comment: Watch sculpting videos. Sculpting organic meshes is way too easier than poly modelling. If you try to join these meshes like you have done above, either it will take a lot of time or it will have very bad topology. I am not that good at organic modelling myself tho. But i would definately learn sculpting for organic meshes

Comment: Ok I’ll try watching some sculpting videos. This sucks though, now I just have a random model of a face

Comment: Although how would I go about sculpting it? Should I aim for putting it on the apple directly or should I sculpt them separate and put them on later?

Comment: You would sculpt both meshes together. Why would you sculpt them separately. That makes no sense

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a stupid question

Comment: jut sculpt out the meshes as you wannt them. Did you try bridging both if these meshes together?

Comment: Yes but the edges were so different they didn’t join correctly. I’ll try this sculpting method though

Comment: You should have the same verts count on both meshes. The provoem is your meshes are very high poly. And maintaining them is quite hard when you have a lot of them. Best of luck on learning sculpting dude